# Finite/Countable support iteration of countable cofinality and mad families

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing

Using a finite support iteration $\langle P_\alpha, \dot{Q}_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa\rangle$ it has been shown that if $\kappa$ has uncountable cofinality, then using Mathias forcing one obtains a mad family of cardinality $\kappa$.

Question 1: Why exactly can't we use this same approach in the case where $cf(\kappa)$ is countable?

Question 2: If finite support iteration for some reason breaks down, could we perhaps instead use countable support iteration?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you could include a bit more information. What forcing notion, what approach? The situation you describe in Question 1 is possible in general.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan I was considering the Mathias forcing notion relativized to the dual filter of the ideal $\{ X \subseteq \omega | \exists Y \in [A]^{< \omega} : X \subseteq^* \bigcup Y \}$, where $A$ is a given almost disjoint family.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan Is there not the potential problem that any finite support iteration adds Cohen reals at countable limit stages which could destroy the ground model mad family?

Comment: No, Cohen reals can preserve some mad families in general. Your forcing construction is still not clear to me. Are you always using the same forcing? Are you diagonalizing against arbitrary almost disjoint families? Are you building one mad family by successively diagonalizing against its already constructed part? Why don't you add the details?

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan Thank you for your helpful comments. The answer to your questions is yes: Starting with an arbitrary almost disjoint family in the ground model, in each successor step of the construction add a Mathias real $m$ to the family from the previous step, where $m$ is of the form $\bigcup \{ x | \exists Y : (x,Y) \in G  \}$, $G$ being the respective generic filter.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan Could you refer me to some good sources (or give me a hint) to see an example of when a Cohen real preserves the madness and when it does not?